# Outlook Keyboard Shortcut to Jump from Task's Subject to Task's Note

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2010

When I open a new task in outlook, the cursor focus is in Subject. I can quickly jump from here to other controls e.g. Priority by <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>. But to jump to notes section I've to go via multiple tab key press. Is there any shortcut to do this?

P.S. My notes are multi line and in rich text format.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will tab through in reverse order.

#### Updated

A workaround: From Outlook, open tasks by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>. Then, set it up by adding 'notes' from Field Chooser (right click where it says subject and you will get the menu to choose field. From here, drag notes into the column titles). Make sure notes is in the second window. This means when you open notes,  you start off in subject, and then tab once to notes. You can actually set the order you want this way.

Comment: yes I know this. But I was searching for one key shortcut. If none, can I assign this (like we do in Visual Studio). Thanks!

Comment: sorry my notes are multi-line and in rich text format :(

Comment: I'll keep looking, but please update your original post to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple way, with the cursor within the *"from here"*, you can press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it will jump to the *"to here"*.

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> is used to travel the tabindex in reverse. Since you need to jump from the first to the last index, it will fit your needs just fine.

---

Additional information about the Outlook 2010 shortcuts can be found at:

[Keyboard shortcuts for Microsoft Outlook 2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/keyboard-shortcuts-for-microsoft-outlook-2010-HP010354403.aspx)

Comment: no it worked for outlook 2007, but not for 2010 :(

Comment: @Ankush Just confirmed, for 2010 it needs 4 reversed. Must be a bug from the program. But still is better than 9 regular tab :)

Comment: yeah... that's what I'm using till now :)

Comment: @Ankush I'm reporting this to Microsoft. In the meanwhile I'll try to find a workaround.

Comment: I already had this (shift tab) in my answer?

Comment: @DaveRook Sorry about that, I didn't noticed the first paragraph!! I've read on your answer the part about `Ctrl+4`...strange... Anyways, I'll keep my answer because I'm actually waiting for some feedback from Microsoft, and also trying to find another way to trigger that jump. If no avail, I'll delete this answer. Once again, my apologies.

Comment: @Zuul - Totally cool - and +1 for suggesting bug.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have Outlook installed to test, but maybe a .VBS similar to the following (which 'presses' Shift+Tab 4 times) will help?

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'The following lines might be required as well

'Do Until Success = True
'  Success = objShell.AppActivate("Outlook")
'  Wscript.Sleep 1000
'Loop

objShell.SendKeys "+{TAB 4}"
WScript.Quit
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156592.aspx

Comment: this looks promising. I'm guessing this can be invoked within outlook. right? how?

Comment: The code above would go into a .VBS file, which can be executed directly in Windows or via a shortcut. I do not know for sure whether this would work, or whether this would even be the best solution.

Just thought of macros/VBA... Maybe something can be cooked up using that instead? Might be a better method given that VBA is baked in:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814736.aspx

Comment: Note that SendKeys can be used in Outlook macros as well. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192656.aspx and http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/3005 for example. So try creating a simple one-liner macro in Outlook that just calls **SendKeys "+{TAB 4}"** and let us know what that does on being invoked via a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

One could easily use a macro recorder such as [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to define a shortcut
for these multiple tab key presses.